# Calculate loss in Pytorch with convolutional network only for image section

Tags: memory, pytorch, loss, dataloader

I have a convolutional neural network that predicts the following frames to a sequence. I have added a border to the image in different colors to give the network additional information. But of course, this additional information is nothing the system should focus on predicting or calculating the loss for. Is there a way to cut the border off before calculating the loss? I've tried:

```
imgs_pred = model(imgs_input)
#compare prediction with what should have happended and calculate loss
#for this, cut frame from image
croppedImages_gt = []
for i in range(0,cfg.dec_frames):
    img_input = imgs_pred[i,:,:,:]
    img_save = ToPILImage()(img_input)
    img_cv2 = np.asarray(img_save)
    img_cv2 = cv2.cvtColor(img_cv2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img_cv2 = cv2.resize(img_cv2, (76,76))
    crop_img = img_cv2[6:70,6:70]
    crop_img = cv2.resize(crop_img, (256,448))
    img_tensor = ToTensor()(crop_img)
    img_tensor_grad = Variable(img_tensor, requires_grad=True)
    croppedImages_gt.append(img_tensor_grad)
croppedImages_gt_tensor = torch.stack(croppedImages_gt, dim=0)

croppedImages_pred = []
for i in range(0,cfg.dec_frames):
    img_input = imgs_gt[i,:,:,:]
    img_save = ToPILImage()(img_input)
    img_cv2 = np.asarray(img_save)
    img_cv2 = cv2.cvtColor(img_cv2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img_cv2 = cv2.resize(img_cv2, (76,76))
    crop_img = img_cv2[6:70,6:70]
    crop_img = cv2.resize(crop_img, (256,448))
    img_tensor = ToTensor()(crop_img)
    img_tensor_grad = Variable(img_tensor, requires_grad=True)
    croppedImages_pred.append(img_tensor_grad)
croppedImages_pred_tensor = torch.stack(croppedImages_pred, dim=0)

loss = criterion_mse(imgs_pred, imgs_gt)
```

It is not beautiful at all, but it has been the first try. I converted the types a lot because I didn't find a function to go from PIL to tensor, no function to go from tensor to cv2, and no function to crop the image in PIL. It is a mess.

But when I executed this without the line "img_tensor_grad = Variable(img_tensor, requires_grad=True)" , it told me that

RuntimeError: element 0 of variables does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

I searched the internet and added the line. Then, the DataLoader can not allocate enough memory anymore. Did I do something wrong?

I also wonder if my DataSet is read in an unfortunate way or anything like that. I found that maybe using a .tar would provide better efficiency, but not how to create my own .tar dataset and read it. Currently, I have 3 datasets (predicting, training, validation), and in each of them are multiple folders with sequences containing 6 frames. These 6 frames are read at once by the DataLoader and given to the model.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something as I have hard time understanding your code, but you should probably prepare GT with borders, compute the network output with borders and crop the tensors before MSE:

```
loss = criterion_mse(imgs_pred[:, :, 6:70, 6:70], imgs_gt[:, :, 6:70, 6:70])
```

In general, you can also mask the pixel loss. That is compute loss without aggregation, multiply it with binary mask and sum the result.